# Stored procedure, subquery returned more than 1 value

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to write a stored procedure in SQL Server that contains a while loop to insert data into my `Employees` table:

```
CREATE TABLE Employees
(
    [EID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Ename] [nvarchar](20) NOT NULL,
    [Gender] [nvarchar](1) NOT NULL,
    [IsMarried] [nvarchar](1) NOT NULL,
    [Birthdate] [date] NOT NULL,
    [HireDate] [date] NOT NULL,
    [Salary] [float] NOT NULL,
    [Notes] [nvarchar](200) NULL,
    [NationalityID] [int] NULL,
    [BossID] [int] NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_Employees] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
)
```

It should work in a way that the number of rows should reach 10, no matter how many rows I had before executing the procedure.

Here's my code:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP05] 
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @TotalCount INT
    SET @TotalCount = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Employees)

    WHILE @TotalCount <= 10
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO Employees(EName, Gender, IsMarried, BirthDate, HireDate, Salary, Notes, NationalityId, BossID) 
        VALUES ('Mirna', 'F', 'M', '7-14-1996', '3-22-2020', 1400, NULL, 1, 2)

        SET @TotalCount = @TotalCount + 1 
    END
END
```

So basically all I get is the following error message:

> Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Procedure Trig_04, Line 7 [Batch Start Line 2]
>   Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

I do have a trigger called `trig_04` that does not allow the user to insert a new employee into the table when his hire date is older than his boss's hire date.

Can anyone help?

This is the trigger code:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[Trig_04] 
ON [dbo].[Employees] 
AFTER INSERT 
AS 
BEGIN 
    IF ((SELECT INSERTED.HireDate FROM INSERTED WHERE BossID <> EID) < 
        (SELECT Employees.HireDate FROM Employees WHERE EID = (SELECT Employees.BossID FROM Employees WHERE BossID <> EID))
    ) 
    ROLLBACK
END
```

Comment: The problem is in the trigger code that you haven't included in your question. Post that code if you need help understanding and fixing the problem.

Comment: Thank you, here's the trigger: CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[Trig_04]
   ON  [dbo].[Employees] 
   AFTER INSERT
AS 
BEGIN
 
 if ((select Employees.HireDate from Employees where BossID <> EID) < 
  (select Employees.HireDate from Employees where EID = (select Employees.BossID from Employees where BossID <> EID)))
 
 Rollback

END

Comment: I added the trigger code in you comment to hoir question. You need to use the virtual `inserted` table to identify the rows inserted by the statement. Otherwise, all rows in the table are evaluated. Also consider an insert statement can insert more than one row at a time.

Comment: I changed it but it still returns the same error. And I didn't understand this part of your comment "Also consider an insert statement can insert more than one row at a time". This was for an exam and the instructor wanted a trigger with a while loop.

Comment: The immediate cause of the error is you are comparing with `=` and this subquery returns more than one Employees.BossID: `(select Employees.BossID from Employees where BossID <> EID)`. SQL Server doesn't know which value you want to compare. Separately, on can insert many rows at once using INSERT...SELECT or INSERT VALUES in the real world so the trigger needs to be able to handle more than one row in the `inserted` table. I suggest you spend some time studying and giving it another try.